# Where to purchase a server capable of 512GB of RAM?

Tags: hardware, memory, scaling, capacity

Where can I purchase a single server capable of 512 GB, yes GB, of RAM?

The most I've seen is 256 GB (32 DIMM x 8 GB per stick)

Comment: I'm curious, what is the use case for this? I imagine it's for an in-memory database?
Have you considered SSD drives instead?

Comment: Sometimes you just want a really big program .. I work in chip design software and we have a 128Gb machine.

Comment: Yes, there are computational and simulation apps that eat RAM for breakfast.  We've got a Dell 910 with 1TB of RAM!

Comment: If that was less of an exciting bit of kit, I expect this question would have been closed by now as a "shopping list" question with an associated thread in meta...

Comment: @w00t: Virtualization.

Comment: Basecamp Next has a server with 864GB RAM http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3090-basecamp-nexts-caching-hardware

Comment: has visions of custom caching layers dancing in his head ->

Comment: @TimK, What's your budget? With enough money you can even get 10x that amount.

Answer (score 14):

The [HP DL700](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/en/WF04a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-3328423.html) series of servers support a maximum of 512GB of memory. The DL785 G6 which is being released in September will also support AMD's new 6 core processors.

Edit:
I made the assumption you wanted x86 architecture here. But, since someone already mentioned Itanium I  think I'll throw in a link to [SGI Altix](http://www.sgi.com/products/servers/altix/4000/configs.html). Their Altix 450 "mid-range" server can go up to 854 GB and 76 cores. The Altix 4700 goes to 1024 cores and 128 **TB** of memory. That's not a cluster, but one shared memory system :) Of course at that point you're looking at several rows of racks of gear for this one "server".

Comment: seconded, they're a great machine and offer some unique memory-protection options - if you're going to buy a server for such a lot of memory it makes sense to get a decent machine. Now just wait until the 780 G6 ;)

Comment: DL785 - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001279.html

Comment: @DanCarley, Do you mean this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/scaling-up-vs-scaling-out-hidden-costs/ ?

Answer (score 4):

Sun makes some really solid hardware.  This one can go up to 512GB of RAM:

http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x4600/index.xml

They also have a couple of SPARCS that can do 1TB of RAM:

http://www.sun.com/servers/finder/index.xml?cat=all&c7eefa02-3698-11de-857b-080020a9ed93=min257.0max8192.0

Comment: It appears the max memory of the x4600 is 392GB or is my math off?

Comment: Actually, it appears from this site that the max memory is 256GB --> http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=1642766

Comment: @Timk: It says pretty clearly in Sun's spec sheet that's it 512 GB.

Comment: There's already a x4600 successor called x4640. It supports 512GB RAM. See http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x4640/

Comment: @jedberg, Links down.........

Answer (score 2):

A good option from IBM is the [x3950](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/x/hardware/enterprise/x3950m2/index.html) enterprise servers. They are System X (x86 / x86_64) servers and you can put up to 256GB (and 4 processors) into one node.

But you can also partition them together and have 4 x3950s acting as a single system, giving you 1TB of memory, 16 CPUs (Mmmm... hex cores gives you 96 cores total).

*(disclosure: My company is an IBM business partner and we sell these systems)*

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider [HP Integrity high-end servers](http://h20341.www2.hp.com/integrity/cache/342254-0-0-0-121.html), as well as a mid-range [rx8640](http://h20341.www2.hp.com/integrity/cache/342108-0-0-0-121.html). Based on Itanium archtecture.

Answer (score 1):

Sun has released the x4640 (the successor to the x4600 mentioned by jedberg earlier) and it supports 512G of memory (64 DIMM slots * 8GB/DIM) and has 8 sockets (up to 48 cores).  It is also only 4RU, so fairly compact for an 8-socket machine.
I have used the x4600s on a few gigs and they have been great to work with.

http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x4640/specs.xml

Answer (score 1):

HP DL 5 now is touting 2TB of RAM  DL580 G7  Starting price $8400 US dollars 4 procs
http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF04a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-3328422.html

$7700 for G7 AMD 1TB memory

Answer (score 0):

Call IBM up, I'm sure they'd be glad to sell you a mainframe with 512 gigs of memory. You won't be able to run windows on it, but you can run either Linux or Z/OS. It will cost you a lot but you are paying for the reliability & service contract as well as the RAM.

Comment: We have several of those 512MB servers running. As someone here already mentioned IBM sells 3950s that can do that.

Comment: @pfo: 512MB servers?  - seems like a far cry from a fair comparison.  I bet that is just a typo..

Answer (score 0):

If you have deep pockets don't mind what CPU architecture you use you can get IBM Power 595 machines with up to 4TB of RAM.  I'm assuming that you want a wintel or lintel server.

For a wintel architecture with support for memory configurations of 512GB or more you can get 8 socket machines from Sun, HP and Unisys.  Unisys also makes a 16 socket Xeon based system that takes up to 1TB of RAM.  Some machines that support this type of configuration are:

- HP DL780/[DL785](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/en/WF05a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-3328423-3716072.html) 8 socket Opteron (and an 8 socket Xeon-based DL780 G6 coming out soon).
- [Sun X4600](http://www.sun.com/servers/x64/x4600/), 8 socket Opteron
- Unisys [ES7000 model 7600R](http://www.unisys.com/products/enterprise__servers/high_d_end__servers/models/index.htm) (16 socket Xeon) and [ES7000 Model 7405R](http://www.unisys.com/products/enterprise__servers/high_d_end__servers/es7405r.htm) (8 socket Opteron).  The 7600R can take up to 1TB of RAM.

One of the other posters mentioned an IBM system that goes up to this spec as well.

Answer (score 0):

We’ve burned one of the ProLiant DL785 G6 servers and what a powerhouse mainframe in a rackable enclosure.  With the older DL760 retired, it’s good to see the monster ProLiant server is back.
http://www.shopricom.com

Answer (score 0):

We just ordered a 512GB machine with 40 cores, a Dell R910 (28K Euro).
Yes, we also need this for de novo assemblies of genomes. In our case, plant genomes.
We didn't buy a 1TB machine, as that would have cost excessive amounts of money.